# popup not active window gets activated

Tags: c++, winapi

I've a popup window which I show with the SW_SHOWNA flag. If I click parts of this window, I catch the click and then close it, the problem is, there are other parts of the window and I don't want to close the window on click on them, but when I click them the window gets activated and gets the focus, that's bad for me, I want this window to stay not activated, and that other window will remind focused.

any ideas?

thanks,
mike.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271795/not-active-popup-window

Answer (score 1):

If you handle WM_HITTEST and WM_NCHITTEST, watch for the points you're interested in, and return HT_NOWHERE for everywhere else, then I think the window shouldn't be activated (I haven't tested this theory).